# How can I stop seeing JVM Full Thread dumps in my AWS EMR Spark job stdout logs?

Tags: java, apache-spark, jvm, amazon-emr, thread-dump

I have PySpark jobs running in AWS EMR. Recently, I upgraded (AWS EMR 6.4, Spark 3.1.2) and switched to running the job in a docker container. Ever since, there are sporadic thread dumps in the stdout logs that start with `Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.312-b07 mixed mode)`.

I've been unable to figure out why they occur. There are no associated errors or warnings in stderr and the job is unaffected. However, these thread dumps make it difficult to read the stdout logs, and I have been unable to figure out why they are happening. Things I have tried include using previous versions of AWS/EMR and even simpler EMR configurations, as I suspected that AWS EMR is sending `SIGQUIT` somewhere, since I did not find anything in the Spark source that would do it (except for thread dumps initiated by the Spark UI, and the Spark task reader, which is disabled).

At a loss for what to do, I would resign to instructing the JVM to redirect these thread dumps or even ignore the signal for them, if that's an option. I am open to alternative suggestions.

I am aware of `-Xrs` but I suspect it's not what I want, since it would likely kill the process on the first `SIGQUIT`.

Comment: Hi, I am facing a very similar issue, though I am seeing them on EC2 with my spring boot app. Did you find an answer? I have searched everywhere online but unable to find anything and chanced upon your post. Also - are you using New Relic? I have a strong feeling these dumps have something to do with that.

Comment: @AdityaK I have not found a solution. I've resorted to writing a script that pulls the logs and redacts the thread dumps. I'm not using New Relic.

Comment: thank you for your reply. After my last message to you, I concluded that this has nothing to do with NR as well. However I notice this issue happens when I am running the app in the docker container with a non-root user. Also, on some occasions, just redeploying the app stopped those thread-dumps. Overall, It still remains a mystery to me.

Comment: Please do comment again if you find out. I will do the same.

Comment: Hi @Maksim we have zeroed down the issue to Amazon Corretto JDK. We found that this issue was happening when running my spring boot app with a non-root user, on an image derived from Amazon Corretto JDK 11.

Comment: Hi @Maksim, we have further confirmation on this - AWS confirmed that this was happening because of a log4j patcher running on the instance. I can provide more info if you need. Thanks.

Comment: @AdityaK thanks, I guess that means we wait until they fix it

Comment: Hi @Maksim .. you have to raise a request with them in order to confirm the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for viewing the logs on the the instance itself or other Unix environment.

By piping the output through a `mawk` filter we can remove the stacktrace when reading or tailing the logs.

On AWS Linux this requires you to install the `mawk` package from the Epel repository.

```bash
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
sudo yum install mawk -y
```

Create a function that creates a tmp filename, tails and filters the input file and write it to the tmp file. Then open the tmp file with `less` and remove the tmp file when the user closes `less`.
The filter removes all lines between `^Full thread dump` and `^\[[0-9`
Which works for me because my logs start with `[2023-09-7 ...`

```bash
less_log() { 
  tmp_file=$(mktemp)
  tail -f -n +1 $1 | mawk -W interactive '/^Full thread dump/{f=1} /^\[[0-9]/{f=0} !f' > "$tmp_file" &
  less "$tmp_file"; kill %; rm "$tmp_file"
}
```

You can now view the logs like this

```bash
less_log /var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/application_1693901863825_0025/container_1693901863825_0025_01_000001/stdout
```

Sources:

- https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/189267-how-ignore-single-multiple-lines-between-while-reading-file-unix.html
- https://superuser.com/a/1600093/1173501
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139295/160014